# Pass vector by value/reference and get iterator from it

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator, implicit-conversion

I want to pass two vectors by value and do some calculations with them. I'm a bit confused why the following does not work. I'm trying to figure this out for hours now -.-

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > Matrix_t;
...
void vector_product(const Matrix_t mc, const Matrix_t mp, Matrix_t& r){
  std::vector<int> _mc(5);
  std::vector<int> _mp(5);
  _mc.insert(_mc.begin(), mc.begin(), mc.end());
  _mp.insert(_mp.begin(), mp.begin(), mp.end());
}
```

I did also try to do this first with Matrix_t& instead of const Matrix_t up to the moment I realized that I don't have to change them inside the function and passing by value is fine too, but it did not work neither.

The compilers prints out a wall of text about conversion errors. Thats the reason I won't copy it in here.

Comment: You cannot change `const` parameters?

Comment: That's not it. Your are trying to to copy elements of type `vector<int>` int a vector with elements `int`

Comment: omg -.- you're completely right, I just added the index and everything works fine. Thanks really a lot!!! I completely oversaw this...

Comment: I think it's better to close this question..this won't help anyone anymore but thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

The local vectors and the vectors returned by the iterators have different value_type.

Iterators return vectors while element of the local vectors are scalar integers.

The value type of these local vectors? defined like

```
std::vector<int> _mc(5);
std::vector<int> _mp(5);
```

is `int` while the value type of the objects returned by the iterators is `std::vector<int>`.

If you would declare the local vectors like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> _mc(5);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> _mp(5);
```

then the code would be valid.